# Yahoo Finance APIs - For Different Stock Exchange

Tags: yql, yahoo-api, yahoo-finance

I actually want to know that whether i can use the Yahoo Finance API to get the data from a specific Stock Exchange. I tried to find the answer and looked through the YQL guide but they didn't mention that how can I specify the stock exchange to get the current share price.

For example I want to know the share price of a company from Australian Stock Exchange and then I want to know another share price of a different company from NewYork Stock Exchange.

Any help is much appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For LSE (London Stock Exchange), all the symbols are just appended with '.L'.

It seems the Australian Stock Exchange is '.AX' (I got the info from this page: https://help.yahoo.com/kb/SLN2310.html )